# WidgetKit preview stopped working after switching to M1 Apple silicon

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, apple-m1, widgetkit

Have recently **switched to M1** Macbook Pro. The project I've been working on stopped previewing the WidgetKit extension file (for other swiftui files preview works as intended). Xcode on my previous machine (**not M1**) previews the WidgetKit file well. Here is the warning I get when trying to preview WidgetKit extension file on M1 mac:

RemoteHumanReadableError

ProcessError: Failed to launch widget extension: The operation couldn’t be completed. (CHSErrorDomain error 1050.)

[image: Xcode screenshot]

Comment: I'd recommend filing a bug with Apple (use generate report and attach that). After that try reinstalling Xcode.

Comment: Any chance you fixed this? It's infuriating getting a brand new M1 mac and having these issues :(

Comment: I tried this: https://medium.com/codex/simple-way-to-use-cocoapods-on-m1-ac9e22cf7e1c. Then deleted all the pods I had and installed them through Swift Package Manager, it worked in the end.